# What happens when binary data is decoded as UTF-8?

Tags: cocoa, utf-8, nsstring

I have a file containing mixed binary and UTF-8 encoded data.

It looks something like

```
-----------------
|  Binary data  |
| (unknown len) |
+---------------+
|   Delimiter   |
+---------------+
|  UTF-8 string |   <--- only relevant part of file
+---------------+
|   Delimiter   |
+---------------+
|  Binary data  |
-----------------
```

I am trying to extract the text, and don't care about the binary content. I'm reading the file into a string decoding everything as UTF-8, then using the `NSScanner` to find the delimiters.

My concern is that, depending on the content of the binary data, decoding it as UTF-8 might cause some sort of offset problem that makes it impossible to find the delimiter. (Say the data right before the delimiter makes the next sequence parse as multiple bytes, and it gets lost.)

Is this code going to have problems with certain content?

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                      error:NULL];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:fileContents]
[scanner scanUpToString@"<DELIMITER>" intoString:nil];
// TODO: remove delimiter
NSString *desiredString;
[scanner scanUpToString:@"<DELIMITER2>" intoString:&desiredString];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you should be worried. In principle, depending on the choice of the delimiter, and the implementation of the UTF-8 decoder, some bytes from the beginning of the delimiter might be decoded as the last bytes of some unicode character being formed by the leading binary data.

In this case you might get lucky, since the characters of your `<DELIMITER>` all fit in within the 7-bit ascii set, while all bytes of a multibyte UTF-8 character will have the 8th (high) bit set in all of the bytes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). The UTF-8 decoder should not grab the '<' as anything else than a '<', but I would not count on it.

It's certainly a good idea to read in the file contents as a binary byte array/buffer, have a delimiter (and make sure it doesn't suddenly randomly appear in the middle of the binary data for some other reason... any such occurrences should be escaped or the binary data encoded somehow so that it cannot contain the delimiter), extract the utf-8 encoded string between the delimiters and then do the utf-8 decoding.

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 multibyte sequences consist exclusively of bytes in the 0x80–0xFF range, so, assuming that your delimiters are literally as shown (`<DELIMITER>` and `<DELIMITER2>`), they consist entirely of characters that can't be part of a multibyte sequence.  (Any pure-ASCII string has this property.)

However, UTF-8 sequences are also length-labeled.  For instance, if you have the three-byte sequence

```
E2 80 3C
```

the E2 indicates that it is the first byte of a 3-byte sequence, but then the 3C cannot be part of that sequence.  A UTF-8 decoder *should* either throw an error or produce the two-codepoint sequence U+FFFD U+003C, but I wouldn't be surprised by a decoder that instead ate the 3C and produced just one REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

Therefore, what you propose is not safe, and you should instead (as oh71zb suggests) read the file in as binary, scan for the delimiters, extract what is between them, and only then interpret those bytes as UTF-8.